# Eclipse subversive reconnect existing project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

In eclipse I have subversive. I imported some existing projects already connected to svn. Yet, subversive doesn't seem to be able to see the svn connection. I've checked the subversive page on http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/faq.php#checked, an d it gives two options. On is to disconnect first, but this option is not available. The second option says that it should just work, which is doesn't. When i right click on project and go to team, the only available options are "Apply Patch...", "Share Project..." and "Share Projecs...".
The repositories on which the projects are hosted are all in the repository list so that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Share Project option. It will recognize that the project is already under version control and offer to work with this information.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I lets me choose between "Aptana Git", "CVS" and "SVN". When I choose SVN it will in some cases give me the option "use project settings". This works. But it does not have this option for all projects.

Comment: Ok, so this already works for most projects for you (and all for me). Try to figure out, what is different with the projects it doesn't work with. Is there a .svn directory? Can you execute svn commands from the console in the project directories?

Comment: Still haven't figured out what went wrong, but it seemed to happen with two very old projects only. I just removed them and checked them out again. Maybe the svn info was of such an old version it was unable to retrieve the correct info?

Comment: I can confirm that Subversive not being able to detect existing Subversion metadata to be due to the SVN Connector not matching the version of the metadata you actually have. Just had this happen to me when I checked out from the command line using SVN 1.7.5 and using the Subversive SVN Connector 1.8.x I could not have Eclipse detect the SVN metadata. After I installed the 1.7.x connector, and selected it in the Subversive preferences, sharing a project would detect the SVN metadata and work properly.