# how to explain eclipse that project on version control

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, ide

I have installed svn plugin for eclipse

[image]

I click right mouse button on project locacted in folder on version control and see next:

[image]

How configure eclipse right?

[image]

if click to share project-> svn I see that on picture above:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse subversive reconnect existing project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428701/eclipse-subversive-reconnect-existing-project)

Comment: d:/ is no protocol as the error mentions. if your svn repository lies there, either make it accessable via localhost or try file:/// as protocol (no guaranty)

Answer (score 0):

press "Share Project" in that menu :) The rest is pretty self explaining, just ask if you face another problem

Comment: 2. it is my local reopsitory

Comment: still use share, there is an option reconnect with existing svn meta info. if this does not work, there might be a version conflict between svn 1.6 and 1.7, then you have to install a different connector in eclipse.